# select query for one-to-many relations table

Tags: sql, json, sqlite, group-by, better-sqlite3

I have 2 tables. These two tables have one-to-many relations.

**TABLE - A**

```
column1 column2
1       label1
2       label2
```

**TABLE - B**

```
Bcolumn1 Bcolumn2 Bcolumn3
1        value1   value4
1        value2   value5
2        value3   value6
```

**RESULT TABLE**

```
column1 column2 json
1       label1  [{"Bcolumn":value1,"Bcolumn":value4},{"Bcolumn":value2,"Bcolumn":value5}]
2       label2  [{"Bcolumn":value3,"Bcolumn":value6}]
```

I want to get RESULT TABLE1 using TABLE - A and TABLE - B.

how can I get this result?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQLite's [JSON1 Extension functions](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html):

```
SELECT a.column1, a.column2,
       json_group_array(json_object('Bcolumn', b.Bcolumn2, 'Bcolumn', b.Bcolumn3)) json
FROM tableA a INNER JOIN tableB b
ON b.Bcolumn1 = a.column1
GROUP BY a.column1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=abf8a38f171284250a2723bec6d1fbd5).

Comment: @Yash this is a different requirement for which you should ask a new question and not update the current question because this way yo invalidate the answers that you already received.

Comment: @Yash this is not the same requirement because your expected results are not a json array. It consists of concatenated values and because of the surrounding square brackets it looks like (but it is not) a json array. So, the solution is different in this case. Also, as I mentioned in my previous comment, editing a question and asking for something different or new invalidates the existing answers and it is discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for in sqlite is the group_concat() function. It's tricky, cause you have he values you want to concat in 2 different columns. Basically you can do the following

```
select
    a.column1
  , a.column2
  , '[{' || group_concat('"Bcolumn":' || b.bcolumn2 || '"Bcolumn":' || b.bcolumn3,'};{') || '}]' as json_output
from tablea a
inner join tableb b on
  a.column1 = b.bcolumn1
group by
    a.column1
  , a.column2
;
```

I tested this solution with MSSQL 2019 and string_agg(), but from the documentation (https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group_concat/) this should work just as well in sqlite.

The trick is to use '};{' as separator, because like this, you will only have to care about the opening and closing brackets and nothing in the middle.

Comment: SQLite supports json aggregate functions to produce json objects. There is no need for concatenations and group_concat().

Comment: You're right, @forpas. I guess in the end it boils down to whether or not you can load extensions or not, though. Depending on server settings, you're stuck with native functions.

Comment: You say this trick '};{' as separator otherwise how to do? can you share an example?